# font-size and line-height set, but changing font still makes an element's height change

Tags: css, fonts

I'm experiencing the following issue in both Safari and Chrome.

```css
body {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

body, .same-font {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

code {
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Without any code - 18px height.</li>
  <li>With <code>code</code> - 20px height.</li>
  <li>With <code class="same-font">code.same-font</code> - 18px height.</li>
</ul>
```

Run the above snippet and the inspector. You can notice that the `code` element doesn't have anything modifying its `font-size` or `line-height` except `body` which it's inheriting from.

It's not adhering to that inherit though, because the height of its containing `li` is 20px, not 18 like the others... I'm not sure where that height is coming from, because the `code` element itself has a height of 17px (which is also of unknown origin).

When the normal/body is applied to the `code` element (like on the third list item), it goes back to 18px like normal. To me this means it's not any other properties that the user agent has imposed on the `code` element affecting the height - solely the `font-family`.

EDIT: For reference, something in StackOverflow's styles prevent this behaviour. The following list items all have the same height:

- One
- `two`
- Three

EDIT 2: Apparently not.. if you change their monospace font to Courier New then the same problem would persist.

**How can this change in size be prevented? i.e. How can you specify a line height that will be used even if the fonts within that line continue to change?**

An example use case would be in a design with vertical rhythm - each line's height and the total height used by an element should be a multiple of 18px (i.e., if using that grid size) - a 20px line throws off the rhythm.

Comment: different fonts have different **default** `line-height` for them, you can't do anything for this. You can't make all of equal `line-height`

Comment: So these fonts just ignore some of their styles? How are we supposed to know which fonts adhere to or ignore these styles? How very strange... EDIT: They don't quite ignore them - if I set it to 30px `line-height`, that would work. If I set it to 10px, then it'd be 18px... What's going on?

Comment: when you'll apply styles to them, they will follow, they don't ignore that.

Comment: That's not the case however, as even if you put `line-height: 18px` on the `li` and `code` in the above example, that middle list item would still be 20px tall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem (to an acceptable extent) by simply tweaking with the font family and size until it worked for me:

```css
body {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

body, .same-font {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

code {
  font-family: Menlo, Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9333em; /* 14/15 */
  line-height: 1.28571; /* 18/14 */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Without any code - 18px height.</li>
  <li>With <code>code</code> - 18px height.</li>
  <li>With <code class="same-font">code.same-font</code> - 18px height.</li>
</ul>
```

**Why Menlo?**

I noticed that StackOverflow used Menlo and that didn't have this problem. When I tried it, it also solved the problem, however the font isn't built in on Windows.

So simply using Menlo solved the problem on Mac and didn't change anything on Windows.

**Why the different `font-size`?**

The different size changed nothing (except the font size...) when Menlo is in use - it still adhered to the line height, so Mac is all good.

However this `font-size` in combination with the Courier New fallback on Windows somehow got it adhering to the line height there too!

If I used 14px instead of 0.9333em it'd still work fine, but if I used 18px for the `line-height` instead of 1.28571, it wouldn't work. That doesn't bother me as I use relative values in my designs anyway.

**So...**

The Menlo font in combination with a Courier New fallback with a different font-size worked to solve my problem to a good-enough extent on Mac (Safari and Chrome) and Windows (Chrome).

My situation is lenient - a pixel difference wouldn't break my design, but just my rhythm. In cases where pixel perfection is required, I wouldn't feel safe with this voodoo method of playing with fonts and sizes...

If anybody can still explain where all of these numbers are coming from and what makes the actual difference here, that'd be great.